# How to disable driver signature enforcement mode if bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON fails?

Tags: windows-10, drivers, bcd, bcdedit

I have been trying to set up some experimental driver, but I have typed quite several times:

```
bcdedit /set loadoptions DDISABLE_INTEGRITY_CHECKS
bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING ON
```

Now I have an error saying:

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>bcdedit /set TESTSIGNING OFF
An error has occurred setting the element data.
Access is denied.
```

[image: command prompt]

I am typing in Administrator prompt.

What should I do to make it work and boot in test mode once again?

Answer (score 0):

I got this same error message and was only able to fix it by going into Safe Mode with Command Prompt, and doing:

```
bcdedit /set testsigning on
```

Safe Mode with Reboot with Driver Signing Enforcement Off (#7), or bcdedit without Safe Mode both did not have any effect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).